# Get puzzled on histogram equalization in Qt

Tags: image-processing, histogram

I'm new to image processing.When I tried the histogram equalization algorithm，I got an error which I can't explain,just as the picture shows below.

I'm sorry that I can't upload a picture right now.I'll use picasa instead.
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/xoxhWR7waVp50uLh-Ko78C_rLSYVGhhn6l5Yer6Tngc?feat=directlink

The original picture is on the left.

My algorithm is turn RGB into YCbCr and equalize Y,leave Cb and Cr be.Then convert YCbCr into RGB again to show the picture after equalization.

Here's the conversion code.

```
void MainWindow::rGBToYCbCr(uchar *bmpArray,uchar *lumaArray,uchar *cBCrArray,int startPoint)
{
    for(int i = 0,m = 0,n = 0; i < bmpWidth * bmpHeight; i++,m+=3,n+=2)
    {
        lumaArray[i] = (uchar)(0.299 * bmpArray[startPoint + m + 2] + 0.587 *bmpArray[startPoint + m + 1] + 0.115 * bmpArray[startPoint + m]);
        cBCrArray[n] = (uchar)(-0.169 * bmpArray[startPoint + m + 2] - 0.331 * bmpArray[startPoint + m + 1] + 0.5 * bmpArray[startPoint + m]) + 128;//cb
        cBCrArray[n+1] = (uchar)(0.5 * bmpArray[startPoint + m + 2] - 0.419 * bmpArray[startPoint + m + 1] - 0.081 * bmpArray[startPoint + m]) + 128;//cr
    }
}

void MainWindow::yCbCrToRGB(uchar *lumaArray,uchar *targetArray,uchar *CbCrArray,int startPoint)
{
    for(int i = 0,m = 0,n=0; i < 3 * bmpWidth * bmpHeight; i+=3,m++,n+=2)
    {
        targetArray[startPoint + i + 2] = lumaArray[m] + (uchar)(1.402 * (CbCrArray[n + 1] - 128));
        targetArray[startPoint + i + 1] = lumaArray[m] - (uchar)(0.344 * (CbCrArray[n] - 128)) - (uchar)(0.714 * (CbCrArray[n + 1] - 128));
        targetArray[startPoint + i] = lumaArray[m] + (uchar)(1.772 * (CbCrArray[n] - 128));
    }
}
```

And here is the equlization algorithm.

```
void MainWindow::histogramEqulizeGrayScale(uchar *bmpArray,int startPoint)
{
    int hisTimes[256]={0};
    for(int i = 0; i < bmpWidth * bmpHeight; i++)
        hisTimes[(int)bmpArray[startPoint + i]]++;
    double pixmapProbability[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            sum += hisTimes[j];
        pixmapProbability[i] = (double)sum / (double)(bmpWidth * bmpHeight);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        hisTimes[i] = pixmapProbability[i] * 256;
    for(int i = 0; i < bmpWidth * bmpHeight; i++)
        bmpArray[startPoint + i] = hisTimes[bmpArray[startPoint + i]];
}
```

Why would the color become so terrible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be that your color values are overflowing?

You have to clamp the results of your calculations for each color to [0,255]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.                                              Do you mean the RGB color value overflows when converted from YCbCr?   I remember that Qt will fix color values to [0,255].And if the value overflows,QPainter should output something,isn't it?But I didn't receive any information.

Comment: :Finally,I got what overflow really means!I stored the color value data in an unsigned char variable and it overflowed!

Comment: @user957121: what did you think it means :) did it work for you then?